# WP7 TextBox automatically add dot

Tags: windows-phone-7, textbox

I have a very simple Windows Phone app with one TextBox. When I type some text, then press Space 2 times, WP7 automatically add a dot.

I dont want the dot. How to handle this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding a dot when pressing "space" two times is a feature from the WP7 keyboard. The user can disable it from the phone settings.

Since it's a global setting, you can't change it. The best you can do it to forbid the user to type dots altogether (when pressing space two times AND when pressing the dot key). If you want to do that, just subscribe to the TextChanged event of your TextBox, and remove the dots.

Comment: thanks for your prompt response. I edited my question about "Space"